# Display Login Name and Role on Every Page Angular 2

Tags: angular, session-state, angular-services, angular-components

I am newer to angular 2; I have an application and I want to display the currently logged in username and assigned role in my header component on every page within my application.  I have:

- user-model (the user interface with necessary fields for display such as username, role, and the person's name)
- user-service (the service class to call the REST end point to get the data from our authentication system

I can easily get the user info from the log in, it comes across as valid JSON, but how do I display it on every page (components) WITHOUT having to call my service on every single component?  Ideally, after the login page the header or starting component will load the user object and inject or pass that to all subsequent components, so the user object is stored (for lack of a better word) from component to component so only 1 http call is needed on application load.

Essentially I am looking for the best, most stream lined approach to this.  It seems like a common scenario, but most people I read who write answers related to this say to call the service in every component.  That would mean an API end point call is initiated on every page load?  Can we store this data in session or cookie?

Thanks!

Comment: If I would manually generate a valid user object and store it in the cookies I could pretend to be someone else?

Comment: As far as I understand..your header component (for example, navbar) should be part of some core module that will be only loaded once and it would contain a call to service to get the currently logged in user. So. there would be just one api call to get the currently logged in user when the app loads. Let me know if my comment make sense.

Comment: @Fran, Potentially yes, someone could manipulate the cookie to mimic someone else (quite easily), I would prefer to steer clear of that.  The good thing is that any cookie information I would store (hypothetical) is not valuable other than a name and display of the role, the real data comes from the secured api end point.  The header merely displays common user information and is not transposed in any way across the app

Comment: @mrsan22, yes your comment makes sense.  I did suspect that.  The trick was to move that user object along to the other components, either by passing as a constructor argument or public property of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a service that holds on to your user. I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

Here is one piece of it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { IUser } from './user';
import { MessageService } from '../messages/message.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    currentUser: IUser;
    redirectUrl: string;

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

    isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return !!this.currentUser;
    }

    login(userName: string, password: string): void {
        if (!userName || !password) {
            this.messageService.addMessage('Please enter your userName and password');
            return;
        }
        if (userName === 'admin') {
            this.currentUser = {
                id: 1,
                userName: userName,
                isAdmin: true
            };
            this.messageService.addMessage('Admin login');
            return;
        }
        this.currentUser = {
            id: 2,
            userName: userName,
            isAdmin: false
        };
        this.messageService.addMessage(`User: ${this.currentUser.userName} logged in`);
    }

    logout(): void {
        this.currentUser = null;
    }
}
```

The key part for you is the "currentUser" property.

NOTE: This is a sample app so the user info is hard-coded. You'd need to retrieve the actual data.

UPDATE: When accessing the `currentUser` from a component, be sure to use a getter. That will ensure you always get the current value if it is changed. I access the current user's name in my MenuComponent, so the code looks like this:

```
  get userName(): string {
    return this.authService.currentUser.userName;
  }
```

If you want the entire user instance, use something like this:

```
  get user(): IUser {
    return this.authService.currentUser;
  }
```

Comment: Excellent.  I will try this option out.  Alternatively, I am calling my service class as a provider inside my app.ts file, and in my header component, I am extracting a service instance from a constructor argument and calling the function that gets the user data, and then simply displaying those values in the HTML of the header.  It works, but not sure if it is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I have a similar case in Angular5. I have the logged in username available in the AuthenticateService. I have a separate component to display the user details in the header. This component is not getting refreshed and reflecting the new username unless I do a browser refresh. I even tried to call ngOnInit() of header component after login was successful. Any help?

Comment: Does your component use a getter to access the user property? Or a simple user property? See the update to my answer above for some sample getter code.